# Cannot map SQL Geography column to EF DbGeography class with dapper

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dapper, sqlgeography

I have table with sql geography column in my SQL database. I have generated entities for my database with EF6. As you know Entitiy Framework generates `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography` for SQL Geography type. I'm using dapper to run queries and map the results into my EF generated entities.

My entity class

```
public partial class Fix
{
    public Fix()
    {
        this.FixUsers = new HashSet<FixUser>();
    }

    public long FixID { get; set; }
    public long UserID { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography Position { get; set; }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual MemberProfile MemberProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FixUser> FixUsers { get; set; }
}
```

SQL query which throw an exception

```
    var fix = SqlConnection.Query<Fix>(@"SELECT TOP(1) 
                                         f.FixID as FixID, 
                                         f.UserID as UserID, 
                                         f.Radius as Radius, 
                                         f.CreatedDate as CreatedDate, 
                                         f.Position as Position
                                         FROM [Fix] f 
                                         WHERE f.FixID = @fixId", new { fixId }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is exception snapshot

[image]

I think by default dapper is trying to map to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography`.

Is there any workaround here?

**EDITED**

Found some solution, created partial class for my entity

```
public partial class Fix
{
    public string PositionString
    {
        set
        {
            Position = DbGeography.PointFromText(value, 4326);
        }
    }
}
```

And changed my query

```
var fix = SqlConnection.Query<Fix>(@"SELECT TOP(1) 
                                     f.FixID as FixID, 
                                     f.UserID as UserID, 
                                     f.Radius as Radius, 
                                     f.CreatedDate as CreatedDate, 
                                     f.Position.ToString() as PositionString
                                     FROM [Fix] f 
                                     WHERE f.FixID = @fixId", new { fixId }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Show your work as a text, not as an image..

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Dapper, you can convert SqlGeography into DbGeography:

```
DbGeography.FromText(sqlGeo.ToString());
```

So just do the conversion in memory, or you can also just use SQL with EF:

```
dbContext.Fixes.SqlQuery("SELECT TOP(1) 
                                     f.FixID, 
                                     f.UserID, 
                                     f.Radius, 
                                     f.CreatedDate, 
                                     f.Position
                                     FROM [Fix] f 
                                     WHERE f.FixID = @fixId", new SqlParameter("fixId", fixId)).FirstOrDefault();
```

or just use Entity Framework the normal way? Since it's not a complicated query :)

```
dbContext.Fixes.Find(fixId);
```

I am still curious why you query with Dapper to then map it to Entities from EF

Comment: I'm using EF just for generating entities for my database.

Comment: @Mkrtich isn't it easier then, to just change the type on the generated entity? DbGeography is designed to be used with EF, and you are using Dapper :) It might also be possible to adjust the T4 template, have you looked into that?

Comment: @Mkrtich There are other micro ORMs that come with T4 templates to generate pocos, you can use PetaPoco's T4 template for example, instead of the EF template. [PetaPoco nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco/)

Answer (score 0):

Dapper has inbuilt support for many common data types, but not all. You might consider using a custom query parameter - you can see how from [this commit](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/c9569d3e24cb95f13d3ee941482ed349c3b7faf6) which adds custom support for table valued parameters as `DataTable`. I would be very reluctant to add anything that demands additional dependencies, especially for things like EF. What perhaps might be useful in the future is a customisable registration tool for custom providers (allowing the data in the parameters to be anything - moving where the map happens). This does not exist today though.

Comment: Problem is not in passing parameter but in getting data from query result.

Comment: @Mkritch ah, ta for the clarification - I'll need to investigate that (at NDC currently - limited access)